# Is Q(u,u) ( also $ \langle u,Av \rangle $ )considered a scalar product? If yes, explain why it is by writing how the scalar product is defined.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, cross-product

I don't know if the following is a good answer: Let $u,v$ be vectors in $\Bbb R^n$, and let $A$ be a random $n×n$ matrix. 
Given that "$Av$" is actually a vector which a matrix has been applied to, we can consider $Av$ as $v$ in new coordinates imposed by the matrix $A$, also $ \langle u,Av \rangle $ is a normal scalar product? Can you tell me if this is a good point or I'm completely wrong?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: What properties do you require for your definition of a "normal" scalar product? You probably have to put some restrictions on $A$ beyond saying it's any "random" matrix. For example, what if $A$ is the zero matrix? Then $\left<u, Av\right> = 0$ for any choice of $u$ and $v$, and you probably don't want that.